# tomcat 7 : SecureRandomAlgorithm

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, java-7

In Tomcat 7.0.30 code :

`org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase` class : code snippet

```
/**
 * The name of the algorithm to use to create instances of
 * {@link java.security.SecureRandom} which are used to generate session IDs.
 * If no algorithm is specified, SHA1PRNG is used. To use the platform
 * default (which may be SHA1PRNG), specify the empty string. If an invalid
 * algorithm and/or provider is specified the SecureRandom instances will be
 * created using the defaults. If that fails, the SecureRandom instances
 * will be created using platform defaults.
 */
protected String secureRandomAlgorithm = "SHA1PRNG";

    /**
 * Return the secure random number generator algorithm name.
 */
public String getSecureRandomAlgorithm() {
    return secureRandomAlgorithm;
}


/**
 * Set the secure random number generator algorithm name.
 *
 * @param secureRandomAlgorithm The new secure random number generator
 *                              algorithm name
 */
public void setSecureRandomAlgorithm(String secureRandomAlgorithm) {
    this.secureRandomAlgorithm = secureRandomAlgorithm;
}
```

Here default is using `SHA1PRNG`. What all possible algorithms i can use here. Is any list available.

I have seen [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) . Here only `SHA1PRNG` is given in `SecureRandomAlgorithm` section.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is only SHA1PRNG implemented. Maybe try `Security.getAlgorithms(String serviceName)` to see, if there are any other? See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getAlgorithms%28java.lang.String%29 and here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#SecureRandom%28%29

Comment: Yup. Its seems like that only but I just want to confirm it.